# Finding $ \int \frac{x-2}{(7x^2-36 x+48)\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}dx$

Tags: integration

Compute :

> $$\displaystyle \int \frac{x-2}{(7x^2-36 x+48)\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}dx$$

I am not able to understand how can I start that question, could someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean the same as I have edited (your language)? I didn't understand what exactly you had written.

Comment: multiply by $(1/x)/(1/x)=1$ and notice that $(x-2/x)'=1+2/x^2$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(14x-36)root(x%5E2-2x-1)dx%2F(7x%5E2-36x%2B48)%5E2

Comment: @mickep Well if so, please write answer.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Done.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755017/how-to-integrate-int-fracx-27x2-36x48-sqrtx2-2x-1dx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From previous similar examples, I had the idea to try the change of variables
$$
u=\frac{x-a}{\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}.
$$
Doing the calculation (which is a good exercise and left for OP), it turns out that if one chooses $a=3$, one arrives at
$$
\int\frac{1}{3+11u^2}\,du.
$$
Integrating, and returning to $x$, we see that

> $$\int\frac{x-2}{(7x^2-36x+48)\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}\,dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{33}}\arctan\biggl(\frac{\sqrt{11/3}(x-3)}{\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}\biggr)+C.$$

I do not see a more systematic way than this.