# How to integrate $ \int\frac{x-2}{(7x^2-36x+48)\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate $$ \int\frac{x-2}{\left(7x^2-36x+48\right)\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}dx\,\,?$$

The given answer is $$ \color{brown}I=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{33}}\cdot \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3x^2-6x-3}}{\sqrt{11}\cdot (x-3)}\right)+\mathcal{C}.$$

I tried by different substitutions i.e $\dfrac{x^2 - 2x -1}{x-3} = t$, but I am not getting my desired answer.

$ORIGINAL$ $QUESTION$:[image]

This question was asked in our test and the given answer was option D ,i.e none on the given options were correct.

Comment: This integral exceeds the standard computation time for WolframAlpha :) (The differential of the answer does not, though.)

Comment: I am a JEE aspirant and this question was asked in our advanced test, so I think there might be a way to solve this problem using fundamentals of integration,@AniruddhaDeb

Comment: The answer can be rewritten as $$-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{\frac{11}{3}}} \cdot \arctan \left( \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 2x -1}}{(x-3)\sqrt{\frac{11}{3}}} \right)$$, which suggests that a possible substitution is $\frac{x^2 - 2x -1}{x-3} = t$. I can't see any other patterns here unfortunately. Also, if it was asked in a test, it must have been an MCQ or somewhat similar question, so reverse engineering would be a viable solution given the limited time you have in the test.

Comment: yes I tried taking $\frac{x^2 - 2x -1}{x-3} = t$ but endedup with an undesired answer,@AniruddhaDeb

Comment: This is not an integration question; it's a differentiation question and the answer is D because when you differentiate $arctan$ or some rational expression containing a single square root, any square root in the result must be a multiple of the square root you started with.

Comment: @Misha that is not our desired conclusion, I mean I need the exact process of how to solve this indefinite integration not through differentiating the options.

Comment: You said you've tried different methods. Can you include those in the question please?

Comment: The intention of the question is most likely to get you to differentiate each of the three options A, B, C, conclude that none of them give the integrand, and then choose option D.

Comment: I agree with @AniruddhaDeb. If this came from an advance test, and if you've tried your hand at manually integrating but couldn't come up with a solid solution, it's a much better strategy to differentiate the options. However I also appreciate you trying to figure out the right process for integrating this expression.

Comment: I tried to differentiate the options in the exam but i felt it was time killing process, so I left this question gave time to the other questions. now I want to know how could this be solved using the substitutions or any process that gives out the desired answer(any other method other that differentiating the options)@sai-kartik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$I=\int \frac{x-2}{(7x^2-36x+48)\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}\,dx$$ This can be simplifies using
$$\frac{x-2}{7x^2-36x+48}=\frac 1{7(a-b)}\left(\frac{a-2 } {x-a }+\frac{2-b } {x-b } \right)$$ where
$$a=\frac{2}{7} \left(9-i \sqrt{3}\right) \qquad \text{and} \qquad b=\frac{2}{7} \left(9+i \sqrt{3}\right) $$ which makes that we are facing two integrals
$$I_c=\int \frac {dx} {(x-c)\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}$$
Complete the square and let $x=1+\sqrt 2 \sec(t)$ which gives
$$I_c=\int \frac{dt}{(1-c) \cos (t)+\sqrt{2}}$$ Now, using the tangent half-angle subtitution
$$I_c=2\int\frac{du}{\left(c+\sqrt{2}-1\right) u^2-c+\sqrt{2}+1}=\frac{2 }{\sqrt{-c^2+2 c+1}}\tan ^{-1}\left(u\frac{\sqrt{c+\sqrt{2}-1}
   }{\sqrt{-c+\sqrt{2}+1}}\right)$$ and so on ....

Comment: Thank you @Claude Leibovici

Comment: @VenkatAmith. Quite tedious, isn't it ? But doable.

Comment: yes, @Claude Leibovici, you re correct it is tedious and doable, but I had not to encounter this problem before!

Comment: @VenkatAmith. Me neither !

Answer (score 5):

Remember:
For such questions, It is always better to differentiate the options in an MCQ format exam.

Since you'd like an approach to integrate this, here goes:)

$$\int\frac{x-2}{(7x^2-36x+48)\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}\, dx = \int\frac{(x-1-1)\,dx}{(7x(x-1)-29(x-1)+19)\sqrt{(x-1)^2-2}}$$

Put $x-1 \rightarrow v$,
$$ = \int\frac{v-1}{(7v^2-22v+19)\sqrt{v^2-2}}\, dv$$
Now put $v \rightarrow \sqrt2\sec y$, $dv = \sqrt 2 \sec y\tan y\,dy$
$$ = \int\frac{(\sqrt2\sec y-1)\sec y}{14\sec^2y - 22\sqrt2\sec y+ 19}\,dy$$
$$ = \frac{1}{7\sqrt2}\int\frac{\sec^2y - (11\sqrt2/7)\sec y + 19/14 + (15\sqrt2/7)\sec y-19/14}{\sec^2y - (11\sqrt2/7)\sec y+ 19/14}\,dy$$
$$ = \frac {y}{7\sqrt2} + \frac{15}{49}\int\frac{\sec y - 19/(30\sqrt2)}{\sec^2y - (11\sqrt2/7)\sec y+ 19/14}\, dy$$
Our denominator here doesn't have real roots. The way ahead would be to factorize the denominator as $(\sec y - a)(\sec y - b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are the complex and then use partial fractions.

Comment: Thank you @Nikunj

Comment: You're welcome and all the best for advanced! :)

Comment: thanks, I thought that this could be done through the applications or substitutions used in indefinite integration which we leart in JEE syllabus, but this doesn't seem like that, but no worries, thanks a lot @Nikunj

Answer (score 3):

By inspection and from the options too, it is clear that the antiderivative has to be of the following form with constants $a$, $b$ and $c$ remaining to be determined.

$$c\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}{ax+b}\right)$$

Differentiation yields the following expression, comparing it with the integrand gives equations in $a$, $b$ and $c$, solving which gives the antiderivative.

$$\frac{c\left(\left(b+a\right)x-b+a\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}\left(\left(a^2+1\right)x^2+\left(2ab-2\right)x+b^2-1\right)}$$

But obviously the answer had to be something different from the ones given in the options, because the term $\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}$ has to remain put inside the $\arctan()$.

Comment: Thank you @Paras Khosla

Answer (score 3):

Apply the Euler substitution $t= \frac{\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}{x-1+\sqrt2}$, along with $a_{\pm}=\sqrt2\pm 1$
\begin{align}
&\int\frac{x-2}{(7x^2-36x+48)\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}dx\\
=&\ \frac2{11}\int \frac{a_+t^2+a_-}
{a_+^2t^4 -\frac{10}{11}t^2+{a_-^2}}dt
= \frac1{\sqrt{33}}\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{11}(a_+ t-{a_-}t^{-1})}{2\sqrt3}\\
=&\ \frac1{\sqrt{33}}\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{33}(\frac x3-1)}{\sqrt{x^2-2x-1}}+C\\
\end{align}